# symfony2 doctrine how to remove related objects in query?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have, for example, a "products" entity and an "orders" entity and a "customers" entity. using doctrine, if I execute

```
return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT p FROM MyApplicationBundle:Products p ORDER BY p.name ASC'
        )
        ->getResult();
```

I get a collection of products with orders and customers related information. this collection is too big and I'm worried it can take too much memory. is there a way to take only the products information? I'd need it only for this query so I don't want to modify the relation in the product entity class.

thanks

Comment: You can specify the fields you to retrieve, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can mark the association as [**Extra Lazy**](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html) in your Entity, this should prevent it from being automatically included in your query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need all the informations in other part of the application, so I prefernot to change it in the doctrine definition